# How should I add System.Data.Table reference in .NETStandard 1.3?

Tags: c#

How should I add System.Data.Table reference in .NETStandard 1.3?

if i use mutiple .net targets and i use datatable then it'll get below message

> CS0234 C# The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

#### My csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net40;net45;net451;netstandard1.3;netstandard2.0;</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard1.3' ">
    <PackageReference Include="System.Dynamic.Runtime" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

#### PS

I found nuget , there's not name System.Data package

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry,I didn't search carefully.

`System.Data.DataTable` is support from .netstandard2.0 version on the official website [DataTable Class (System.Data) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.7.2)

I have to use `#if !NETSTANDARD1_3` to do it for mutiple .net target version.